# intl-tel-input jquery plugin utilsScript loading error

Tags: jquery, intl-tel-input

I'm using intlTelInput jquery plugin, which I tried to include the utilscript option

```
$("#phone).intlTelInput({
        utilsScript: "utils.js"
      });
```

when loading utilscript i'm getting an error(Uncaught ReferenceError: goog is not defined)

Comment: I am seeing the same error if I use jQuery 3.3.1, but no error with jQuery 2.1.3. Would love a solution as I don't want to include the older jQuery version.

Answer (score 0):

Update the entire plugin and don't forget to use the correct relative path for the utils.js file